# Query for sub-array in multi-dimentional array

Tags: postgresql, array

How do I fix the following sql query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS array_test;

CREATE TABLE array_test (
  id serial primary key,
  name text,
  array_column integer[][]
);

insert into array_test (name, array_column) VALUES
  ('rowa', '{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}'),
  ('rowb', '{{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}');
```

This following query triggers a syntax error. How do I query for values with this sub array?

```
select * from array_test where '{1,2,3}' = ANY (array_column);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way in Postgres 9.3+ with [`generate_subscripts()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   array_test a
JOIN   LATERAL generate_subscripts(a.array_column, 1) i
               ON a.array_column[i:i] = '{{1,2,3}}'::int[];
```

This way I am comparing whole slices of a 2-dimensional array. Note the double curly braces!: `'`**`{{`**`1,2,3`**`}}`**`'`. `LATERAL` and a join condition is probably the shortest syntax. If your slices are not unique within each array, rather use an `EXISTS` semi-join to get unique rows in the result (also works with older versions):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   array_test a
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   generate_subscripts(a.array_column, 1) i
   WHERE  a.array_column[i:i] = '{{1,2,3}}'::int[]
   );
```

If you are unfamiliar with the Postgres array implementation, this may seem contrived. Read on ...

Defining a column as **`integer[][]`** (signifying a 2-dimenstional array) is effectively the same as just `integer[]`, because Postgres does currently not differentiate array data types with different dimensions. Each array type can have any number of dimensions as long as they match up internally.

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION)

> The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of
>   dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all
>   considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of
>   dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in
>   `CREATE TABLE` is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time
>   behavior.

The simple expression:

```
WHERE 1 = ANY (array_column)
```

... tests for equality with any **base** element, ignoring dimensions completely. Per documentation

> The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each **element** of
>   the array using the given operator.

Bold emphasis mine. It's just not possible to compare array slices this way.
Similar with [array operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE):

```
WHERE '{1,2,3}'::int[] <@ array_column
```

... would match for all arrays that include all of the **base** elements, again regardless of dimensions.

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html)

> Array comparisons compare the array contents **element-by-element**, using
>   the default B-tree comparison function for the element data type. In
>   multidimensional arrays the elements are visited in row-major order
>   (last subscript varies most rapidly). If the contents of two arrays
>   are equal but the dimensionality is different, the first difference in
>   the dimensionality information determines the sort order.

Bold emphasis mine.

Related older answer on SO with some other techniques:

- [PostgreSQL two dimensional array intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11883325/939860)